# Semaphore in Java

Tags: java, semaphore

My code:

```
public class t3 {

static int i = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1);
    sem.release();
    System.out.println(i++);    //1 then ++
    sem.release();
    System.out.println(i++);    //2
    sem.acquire();
    System.out.println(i++);    //3
    sem.acquire();
    System.out.println(i++);    //4
    sem.acquire();
    System.out.println(i++);    //5
    sem.acquire();
    System.out.println(i++);    //6
    sem.acquire();
    System.out.println(i++);    //7
    }
}
```

My output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Why is not like this:?

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Comment: @ZouZou: I didn't know either, but it is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html

Comment: OK guys, my bad :) Didn't know it exists.

Comment: What I don't understand is "What is not clear about semaphore?" :)

Comment: This can be answered by reading the javadoc of Semaphore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Semaphore is pool of permissions. At start

```
Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1)
```

contains only one permission but since you used `release` two times you added two more so it has 3 of them in total. Next you invoked `acquire` five times but since there ware only three permissions in semaphore 4th invocation of `acquire` makes your thread wait for available permission.

To see it more clearly take a look at comments in this code

```
Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1); // 1 permission available
sem.release();                    // 2 permissions available after this method
System.out.println(i++); // 1 then ++
sem.release();                    // 3 permissions available after this method
System.out.println(i++); // 2
sem.acquire();                    // 2 permissions available after this method
System.out.println(i++); // 3
sem.acquire();                    // 1 permission available after this method
System.out.println(i++); // 4
sem.acquire();                    // 0 permissions available after this method
System.out.println(i++); // 5

sem.acquire();                    // now thread needs to wait for available permission
System.out.println(i++); // 6
sem.acquire();
System.out.println(i++); // 7
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the permit counter goes like: 0, -1, -2, -1, 0, 1 and then blocks. Because you have one permit available. It seems that The permit counter works the other way around so, it starts at 1 and then goes like 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0 and block. (Thanks @JB Nizet)

Comment: It's in the other way: 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0 -> blocked. relase() adds a permit. acquire() gets one and decrements the number of permits, or blocks if none is available.

Answer (score 1):

You should notice that your process did not finish, it was stuck in a wait state.
Run the version of the code below and vary the initial values passed to the Semaphore constructor you should be able to get a feel for the behaviour.
You should notice that each time you call release() you increase the available permits,
and each time you call acquire() you decrease the size of the pool.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1);

    sem.release();
    System.out.println(sem.availablePermits() + ":" + i++);    //1 then ++
    sem.release();
    System.out.println(sem.availablePermits() + ":" + i++);    //2
    sem.acquire();
    System.out.println(sem.availablePermits() + ":" + i++);    //3
    sem.acquire();
    System.out.println(sem.availablePermits() + ":" + i++);    //4
    sem.acquire();
    System.out.println(sem.availablePermits() + ":" + i++);    //5
    sem.acquire();
    System.out.println(sem.availablePermits() + ":" + i++);    //6
    sem.acquire();
    System.out.println(sem.availablePermits() + ":" + i++);    //7
    }
}
```